# Calculate derivative for provided function, using finite difference, Python

Tags: python, function, reference, derivative

I should probably start by saying that I am relatively new to python, but I have coded in java and Matlab before.

In python, the code

```
def func(f):
    return f
g = func(cos)
print(g(0))
```

gives the result

```
>1.0
```

as `g` now is defined as the cosine function.

I want to write a function that calculates the derivative of any provided function using a finite difference approach. The function is defined as

```
def derivator(f, h = 1e-8):
```

and would like to achieve the follwing:

```
g = derivator(cos)
print(g(0)) # should be about 0
print(g(pi/2)) # should be about -1
```

At the moment my derivator function looks like this

```
def derivator(f, h = 1e-8):
    return (f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2))/h
```

which definitely is wrong, but I am not sure how I should fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Notice that you can compute derivates by using [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html).

Comment: Could I ask why you do `(f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2))/h` instead of `(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/h`? I'm not saying you're wrong, my calculus is just a little rusty.

Comment: @JamesKelleher It's a [different kind of derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative). The one OP uses is slightly more complicated, but it's also (usually, I think) slightly more accurate when approximated like this.

Comment: @Theano: The task is to write a function that does it, so even if it is a roundabout way of getting the derivative, it is what I am stuck with.

Comment: @JamesKelleher: It's just a matter of step length really, but in your suggestion one would need to put 2*h in the denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current `derivator()` function (which should probably be called `differentiator()`) uses an undefined variable `x` and would return a single value, if `x` were defined--the value of `f'(x)`. You want to return a function that *takes* an x value. You can define an inner function and return it:

```
def fprime(x):
    return (f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2))/h
return fprime
```

Because you don't use that function anywhere else, though, you can use [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) instead, which is also shorter:

```
return lambda x: (f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2))/h
```

The only thing PEP 8 [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id42) about lambdas is that you should *not* assign the result of the lambda to a variable, then return it:

```
fprime = lambda x: (f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2))/h  # Don't do this!
return fprime
```

Comment: Never thought of using an inner function, brilliant!
And I should also read up on lambda functions.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Make an inner function inside your `derivator` function and return it:

```
from math import cos, pi

def derivator(f, h = 1e-8):
    def g(x):
        return (f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2))/h
    return g

g = derivator(cos)
print(g(0)) # 0.0
print(g(pi/2)) # -0.999999993923
```

`f` and `h` will be part of the closure of the returned function.

You can also return a lambda expression to make it one line:

```
return lambda x: (f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2))/h
```

Comment: I like how we both posted different answers, then saw the other's and added the same content to our own.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!
Never thought of using an inner function, great stuff. And I should probably look into lambda expressions, thank you!